# Cancel navigation on a frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, frameset, frameset-iframe

Say I have a frameset with a frame where Google is loaded. I want to prevent Google from navigating anywhere when the user click on a link or a button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.
The only way that comes into my mind is to use a simple Javascript code in the parent frameset to detect when the child frame containing Google Home Page has been reloaded because user pressed a link in it, and then force the child frame to reload again the Google Home Page. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var flag_1st_time_call = true;
   function ReloadGoogleHome()
   {
      if(!flag_1st_time_call)
      {
         document.getElementById('myframe').src = "http://www.google.com";
      /* I'm not sure you can get frame with document.getElementById (I'm 
         more confortbale with IFRAMEs) anyway I think you understood the example */
      }
      flag_1st_time_call = false;
   }
</script>

<frame src="http://www.google.com" id="myframe" onload="ReloadGoogleHome();"></frame>
```

**This does not prevent user to click on links and display for a while the page where they navigated too, but suddenly they will be brought back to Google HOME PAGE.**

Another possible solution (if you were using IFRAME in a page to show Google instead of a frameset) is to create a position aboslute div element in the parent page (the one that contains the IFRAME) with opacity and make it cover the IFRAME, **in this way user won't be able to interact at all with the Google page displaied in the IFRAME**.